# Bacon.js: redo ajax request on error

Tags: javascript, ajax, bacon.js

I have an array of urls I want to make get requests to. I create a stream from the urls array, and flatMap ajax requests, like so:
responses = Bacon.fromArray(url_arr)
  .flatMap(function(url) {Bacon.fromPromise($.get(url))})

Now, in the responses stream, I want to keep redoing the ajax until I get the value. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use flatMap and [Bacon.retry](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/blob/master/src/Bacon.coffee#L265)

```
Bacon.fromArray(url_arr).flatMap(function(url) {
    return Bacon.retry({
        source: function() { return Bacon.fromPromise($.get(url)) },
        retries: 5
    })
}).onValue(function(value) {
    console.log("Done: " + value)
}).onError(function(e) {
    // handle error
})
```

You can check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o1spf5co/2/), where I use Math.random() to simulate the ajax requests.

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursion like this:

```
var pollUrl = function(url) {
  return Bacon.fromPromise($.get(url)).flatMap(function(response) {
    if (ok(response)) {
      return Bacon.once("response OK");
    }
    else {
      return pollUrl(url);
    }
  })
}

Bacon.fromArray(url_arr).flatMap(pollUrl);
```